# Geometry seems to disappear when attempting to separate objects

Tags: geometry

I'm attempting to model a .45 ACP bullet as a practice exercise, and am exceptionally new to Blender (if not StackExchange).

The modified cone - the upper element - is the bullet, and he cylinder - the lower element - is the cartridge, and is incomplete (**first image**).

I am attempting to separate the cartridge from the bullet, so that, once both are unwrapped, I can assign different textures to both of them (copper for the bullet; brass for the cartridge). The complete model will have them intersecting one another where the bullet would meet the cartridge on an actual .45 ACP round, but for now they're not touching one another in the editor so that they're easier to work on.

However, when I press "separate", the geometry of the cartridge appears to be deleted. The mesh is still there, but there are no longer vertices, and it can no longer be colored or unwrapped (**second image**).

How do I make both the cartridge and the bullet two separate objects with their own geometry?

[image]

[image]

As an aside, I have no clue as to what to tag this, so edit whatever you want in that regard.

Comment: "*I am attempting to separate the cartridge from the bullet, so that, once both are unwrapped, I can assign different textures to both of them*" https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos While your link will be helpful for me later - thank you for it - I don't want to assign materials to my bullet in Blender. I want to make each component a separate object so that they can be unwrapped separately from one another. Sure, if I do that, they might share the same file, but when I apply textures to one they won't automatically be applied to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry is still there, but Blender only shows the detailed mesh for the one object that you are editing.  By separating the meshes, you've made the cartridge into a second mesh as you can see in the outliner.  Exit edit mode, select the cartridge and enter edit mode and you will see its geometry but not the geometry of the bullet.

Comment: Annnd there's my answer - it worked, thank you. +1.